# Symbol "vector" could not be resolved

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using the  standard file, I"m also using the Eclipse IDT. When I use the vector template in my header files, I get "vector does not name a type" error, or I get "Type 'vector ' could not be resolved". I am able to use vector fine in .cpp files in the project. I'm including the header file code below

```
#ifndef TX_H_
#define TX_H_
#include <vector>

class Tx {
    int nT;
    vector<float> beamform;
public:
    Tx(int);
    virtual ~Tx();
    vector <float> Trans(float);
};

#endif /* TX_H_ */
```

The line "vector beamform" produces the  "vector does not name a type" error. The line vector  Trans(float); produces the "Type 'vector ' could not be resolved" error. Please advise. I do need to pass vectors as parameters. So, if I'm not allowed to declare vector types, what is the workaround ?

Comment: Use `std::vector`

Comment: It's `std::vector`, not `vector`.

Comment: Just a note: *don't* pull the `std` namespace into global via `using` when you fix this. That's neither ideal nor warranted, so don't even consider that. Use proper namespace qualification (`std::vector`) as described above. [Read this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) to better understand what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

> vector does not name a type

You get this error because `vector` is declared in the `std` namespace. You need to write `std::vector<float> beamform;` instead.

Comment: that fixed it!
I added "using namespace std;" cleaned and rebuilt the project. On to other issues.
Thanks!